# How to prevent premature JavaScript warpping with PrettierJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, prettier

I have a PrettierJS setting that is causing wrapping that I don't want.  Unfortunately, I cannot find the setting.  How can I PREVENT these lines...

```
if (err) { return next(err); }
const { joinCode } = req.appData;
```

.. from looking like this?..

```
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}

const {
  joinCode
} = req.appData;
```

Comment: Well, provide us with your eslint configuration then! Otherwise any response would be speculation on what's causing it.

Comment: Are you using eslint? If so, I might try searching for keywords "curly" or "brackets" in [ESLint Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).